# Can't use boot-repair tool to repair the bootloader of my ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader, bootrepair

I followed the tutorials on internet, which told me if I can't boot my ubuntu appropriately(coz I changed my motherboard, the boot-loader has been overwritten), I need to use a bootable usb and use the boot-repair app. But during my using, I only found **one button** in the interface of boot-repair. I clicked it, and it doesn't work. This picture is what I see.

[image]

And this is the **log**:

```
boot-repair-4ppa161                                              [20220116_1255]
```

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

=> Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32832 of /dev/sda1 for its
                   second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed.
                   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg
                   /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys
```

================================ 0 OS detected =================================

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHDGraphics620 from   Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,9434477c-03d0-44b9-b6ef-0032f536cf5c,0x800,0x145000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...8................
Boot0001* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0002* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP,0x0)..BO
Boot0003* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0004* Onboard NIC    BBS(Network,IBA CL Slot 00FE v0112,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(17,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xab7f6a6,0x800,0x39bf800)..BO

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0ab7f6a6
Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 60555263 60553216 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:31.0GB:31.0GB:fat32::boot, lba;

Free space (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:29568MiB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:0.03MiB:1.00MiB:0.97MiB:free;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda
└─sda1 vfat     4091-A721                            0ab7f6a6-01                          UBUNTU 20_0

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

```
    Avail Use% Mounted on
```

sda1    26.3G   9% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
        ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
```

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
        ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
        ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
```

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you overwrote the boot loader, easiest is to reinstall Linux.

1. Make a complete disk image with dd or other tool.
2. Reinstall Linux.
3. Copy over any files you need from the image.